# VIsual Studio Tools for Cordova - Suddenly the Cross Domain Proxy (CORS) is not working

Tags: android, cordova, proxy

I have build an App using VS 2013 Update 4 and Tools for Cordova CTP3. Everything has been working very good, but suddenly (without changing anything, or at least not knowing what i changed) it seems the Cross Domain Proxy stopped working.

If i build a distribition build, and deploy it to either iPhone or Android it works as expected.
If i run in Ripple or debug on the Android device, i get an error like this:

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

```
It tries this Url: http://localhost:4400/ripple/xhr_proxy?tinyhippos_apikey=ABC&tinyhippos_rurl=http%3A//www.mydomain.dk%3A84/umbraco/Api/MemberApi/Login%3Fpassword%3DXXXXXX%26userName%3Dkb
```

If i run the url in the browser i also get: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I have tried the following different settings in the config.xml:

```
<access origin="*" />
<access origin="http://*" />
```

If i disable the Proxy in Ripple i get:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.mydomain.dk:84/umbraco/Api/MemberApi/Login?password=XXXXXX&userName=kb. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4429' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405.
```

My Chrome version is Version 39.0.2171.95

Any help will be greatly appreciated

br
Michael

Comment: Have you checked the actual server that should answer on the localhost:4400?

Comment: The 4400 is the ripple proxy, so not sure how it can not work

Answer (score 0):

This is the meta tag that works with me for logging in to an external resource and the app redirected back to one of the app pages.

```
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'">
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

The following line from above:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4429' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405.
```

This is basically telling you why it is failing. You need to pass a Custom Header with each cross domain request your application is making.

If you have a web.config in your project can you add the following line:

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="XXX"/>
```

The 'XXX' is the cross domain url you wish to have access to.
Add the above line to the following section of the web.config

```
<system.webServer>
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
      <!-- Put custom header here... -->
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Regards

Craig

Comment: Hi Craig
I am aware of that, but it has been working for months without that, so why is it suddenly now needed.
Also i guess that is what the Proxy is for?

Comment: He's wrong, Cordova is not subject to CORS, that is for web browsers only, which Cordova is not. I gave up on Ripple and have a much more enjoyable experience just developing on a real device and using Chrome's build in Android usb debugger and proxy to access resources using the dev machine's internet connection. WAY more reliable.